# Burp Suite on Tails

Tags: tails

I'm trying to set up Burp Suite on Tails, however, it seens that the port 127.0.0.1:8080 is not being open by Burp Suite. Does anyone here already installed and used Burp Suite successfuly on Tails? How should I procede? Thank you guys ;)